# Can Google Cloud App Engine HTTP request have multiple 'responses'?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to deploy a program that might exceed the 24 hours response limit.

My initial solution is Cloud Function. But Cloud function has an execution timeout of 9 mins.

Then I found App Engine doesn't have execution timeout but has a 24 hours response limit.

Can Google Cloud App Engine HTTP request have multiple 'responses'? so I can keep the program running longer. Can the code be executed after the program sends a response?

Comment: I am not sure of the correct answer as I have not tested this scenario. App Engine has a proxy / load balancer in front (GFE). This buffers your HTTP response until complete. This means that you cannot send partial responses to keep a service alive past the max duration of 24 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if I am understanding well your question but I think this could be very helpful for you.

App Engine runs multiple instances of your application, and each instance has its own web server for handling requests. Any request can be routed to any instance and any instance can handle multiple request concurrently. You are able to adjust the number of instances in your the app.yaml. At this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled) you can find more details about it.

On the other hand, App engine standard with basic scaling allows you [up 24 hours for HTTP request and task queue tasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types). So, I think that you can use
[Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview) to execute the code as you mentioned. As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue), "Task queues let applications perform work, called tasks, asynchronously outside of a user request". The Task Queue service is designed for asynchronous work.